# Android phones cannot receive the MMS from our App (VAS-App) while the feature phone does

Tags: java, android, soap, mms, mm7

We developed an App for a mobile operator (VAS App). When user uses the app he receives an MMS finally.
This is working properly if the user has a feature phone.
But if a user uses an Android phone he doesn't receive the MMS.
Only a notification about the MMS. but cannot download the MMS.

Please help me on this. We are in a big trouble now and cannot identify where the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why this is down voted? . This is a real problem we have. :(

Comment: It was probably downvoted because you did not provide much information. Android does support MMS, so there is probably something wrong with your code. I suggest you post the relevant code, including the relevant part of the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
this is not an Android Project. Its a VAS-App Which is Value Added Service for Mobile operator. User only request the service and then the VAS App send the request to the MMSC to send the MMS to the requested user.

Comment: I see. Then I can attempt answer:

Comment: People are down voting this problem because they cannot understand. yes I also cannot understand this because why this problem is occur. If its working for feature phones why it is not working for android devices. device is matters only when receiving the MMS. As per my knowledge MMS having a common format for all devices. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is something incongruous about the format of the MMS message that Android doesn't like. I don't know enough about VAS-Apps to be of much help, except that you may be able to:

1. compare two MMS message formats, one working and one not, to find the discrepancy
2. look at the Android source code for how it handles MMS

Comment: Yes that is better to look into Android Source code. But the problem is if normal MMS are working on Android, the problem is in our App. But at the same time it works for normal feature phones. :(
Anyway Thank you, we will try something with Android Source.

Answer (score 0):

**Got to know that sending a soap with a SMIL message will solve the problem.**
But again the problem is how to attach the SMIL message in to SOAP in java.

Thank you